# How much do potential employers for an entry level engineering job (requiring a bachelors) care about Solidworks Professional certification?

Tags: hiring-process, hiring, employment, entry-level, certification

How much do potential employers care about whether you have [Solidworks Professional](https://www.solidworks.com/) certification (or rather how much of an advantage does it give you) if you are applying for your first job in engineering after getting your bachelor's degree? Is it worth the money, or is it just a relatively useless title that doesn't really matter for employment?

Of course I know that it isn't a substitution for skill or a good degree, but with all things being equal, how much of a difference does having the certification make to your chances of being hired or your initial salary?

Comment: none to most, it's not a recognised mainstream cert. Only relevant to someone who knows it or uses the tools

Comment: What line of work are you looking for?

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of the Off Topic-"Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else"

Comment: There exist job descriptions with this certificate in their required education/qualifcations section. To those employers, I would wager that it matters very much.

Comment: Really? Maybe if it is one of a few requirements, and not just part of a kitchen sink wishlist.

Comment: I disagree with the answer that you accepted.

Let's try another approach :

 - how much will the course cost you?
 - what's the average starting salary for your industry?

 - find a popular job site (maybe Moster.com?) that is relative to you - how many openings are there that match you?

 - how many of them are asking for solidworks?

 - how many state it as "must have"? as opposed to "nice to have"?

What's your potential return on investment?

Comment: Do you need the certification, or just to know how to use it? They offer  a free trial. If you apply yourself, you should learn enough in the trial time to be able to talk well enough about it in a an interview to show that you know it, thus saving hundreds, possibly thousands of $$$. If t hat’s not enough time, you could request a trial extension (I have done this before), or use a fake email address (if you conscience permits it), or have a friend or family member sign up and “help” them to learn it ...

Comment: ... Or you could get a trial copy of AutoCAD (which is the most popular CAD program in industry), or the free OpenCAD. They don’t all have identical features, but the core is the same. In fact, if your job requires CAD knowledge then I would expect you have it from your studies, which would be enough for me as hiring manager. Save yourself the $$$

Comment: I'm talking about the certification if you already have the skills. The certification is $90 and takes about 3 hours. You can do it at home (or wherever you have the program installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH, so this is a good question.

I think that evidence of training and ongoing development is *good*. In many industries, people pay for their own training courses - CFA, AWS, MBAs - and do them on their own time.

The training is to help you do better at the job, or to outright switch career. Internal company training is rarely as useful, it's generally more around the processes that the company wants to occur.

You've asked a mite too specific a question - you're asking about the solid works thing. The obvious answer to the more general question (ie about training) is, of course, "a lot". Companies obviously care how well trained you are - try breaking into a corporate job without a degree, for example. Or even an unfinished degree - it will be harder than if you have the degree.

Given that companies care about training, you also have to realise companies care about the *type* of training. You might have a degree in Astrophysics, but you won't easily get a job in marketing, for example.

So to your particular question - it will depend on if the company in question uses or needs the solidworks program.

I would recommend you get a list of target companies and just ask them, and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

I had no idea what it was, and had to Googled it (I added a link to the question).

The company's web site says:

> SOLIDWORKS 2018 provides four new solutions to help you simplify
>   interactions between product development teams and ultimately improve
>   your business.

And you say that:

> you are applying for your first job in engineering after getting your
>   bachelor's degree? Is it worth the money, or is it just a relatively
>   useless title that doesn't really matter for employment?

Short answer: No

Longer answer: this looks like it might be marginally useful ***for someone who’s job it is to “simplify interactions between product development teams”***, (and then only if the company already uses, or can be persuaded to invest in it);  that is highly unlikely to be you, in your first job.

If I were interviewing you, then like Shania Twain, I would be thinking “that don’t impress me much”.

Tl;dr:  don’t pay from your own pocket for extra training (in most countries, that degree already cost you a fair whack).  If the company thinks that you need training to do your job, be productive and earn them money, then the company will pay for said training.

Comment: Lolx ! Good point. It was only Shania on YouTube, singing that don’t impress me much”, but if you click it, with sound on ... :-)  Thanks for removing it (+1)

Comment: no worries, i figured it was that song but i didn't want to actually check and find out!

Comment: Solidworks is a CAD program that is often used by engineers to design parts. The professional certification is evidence that you are proficient in using it.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's relatively new to the market; there are well established CAD Programs, and I never heard of that one.

Comment: @Mawg I would personally say that SolidWorks has been an established CAD program for ~15 years.

Comment: That I did not know; thanks (and upvote) for the clarification